# Where to find embedded JS function for Neo4j traverse REST API

Tags: neo4j, traversal

I am new to Neo4j, and I read the documentation for traverse part by REST, there is an example here:

http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/rest-api-traverse.html#rest-api-traversal-using-a-return-filter

{
  "order" : "breadth_first",
  "return_filter" : {
    "body" : "position.endNode().getProperty('name').toLowerCase().contains('t')",
    "language" : "javascript"
  },

Is anybody can tell me what I can find the information about position, endNode(),getProperty...., it likes an embedded javascript function, but i do not know the meaning of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [Traversals documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/rest-api-traverse.html):

> The position object in the body of the return_filter and
>   prune_evaluator is a [Path](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html) object representing the path from the start
>   node to the current traversal position.

You can start with the JavaDoc for [Path.endNode()](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html#endNode()) to understand how to interpret the `return_filter`.

[ADDENDUM, to answer a comment]

If you want to filter the traversal by label, you can use Node.hasLabel(), like this:

```
"return_filter" : {
  "body" : "position.endNode().hasLabel(DynamicLabel.label('t'))",
  "language" : "javascript"
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It is wired why I did not notice this sentence.

Comment: Hi Cybersam, would you please answer me one small question, If I want to filter the traversal by label, how should I make it? I wrote:                                 "return_filter" : {
    "body" : "position.endNode().getLabels().next().value.contains('α')",
    "language" : "javascript"
  },           it seems not right as I do not know how to handle the iterator here. thanks very much

Comment: Hi Cybersam,  Sorry I have to interrupting you again, as I really do not know how to solve it.  can you go to my another post? thanks very much fo ryour patient and sorry for wasting your time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481736/playing-neo4j-in-embedded-database-way